# Is it valid to use AWS SQS as a write queue to Aurora database to increase system performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, message-queue, amazon-sqs, amazon-aurora

I am developing a web application server on AWS that need to support high throughput on reading and write. My boss gave me a high-level design like this.

[image]

I am stuck on the "Write Queue". The team told me that we need it to increase the performance of writing because we can have only 1 master replica to which we can write. I have some basic knowledge about message queues such as SQS and RabbitMQ but don't know anything about using it as a database write queue.

**At the current stage, I have 3 questions:**

1. Using this architecture, is it really able to increase the performance of writing to the database (as opposed to writing directly to the master replica).
2. How to handle transactions, especially how to rollback, when errors occur during the writing. Normally, we would control the transaction in application code such that when an error occurs, the whole transaction is rollback and the App Server response to the client with some error code.
3. I mentioned that I have researched about using message queue as a write queue, but I am not sure if I am looking in the right direction. Maybe, there is some other technology already that is suitable to be a write queue to the database?

In addition to the questions, I believe this should be a big topic and would like to know the resources where I can research in detail on this topic.

Comment: IMHO the queue should only be viewed/used as a buffer, should there be times when the database itself could not easily handle the number of incoming inserts.  At the end of the day, the queue would only be able to write as much as the database can already handle.  You might want to also make certain that you really need a queue here, as it will complicate your application logic, and also make debugging harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In similar cases, queues are used as a mean for de-coupling two systems. There are several advantages and disadvantages when implementing such architectural patterns. I will try to list what I believe are the main ones.

**Advantages**

1. Improved response time

   As queues do not require complex transactions they are usually a fast and, if correctly configured, safe storage. This means the perceived response latency from the client side will decrease giving the feeling that the service is "faster".
2. Separation of concerns

   Correctly de-coupling services increases their resilience to errors. For example, if the DB cannot accept more write requests, the clients will be unaffected and their requests will still not be lost as they will be in the queue. This gives Operators more time to react to problems while the service value is only partially affected.
3. Improved scalability

   When operations become complex, it's usually a good idea to separate them into microcomponents. It is way easier to scale up microcomponents than monolithic services. Job queues enable such design patterns.

**Disadvantages**

1. Recovering from errors becomes more complex

   As said above, if the DB stops accepting requests, jobs will pile up in the queue. Now you have 2 problems to deal with: a full DB and a full job queue. System problems start propagating across your architecture like ripples causing several side effects and making hard to understand what is the root cause.
2. Identifying bottlenecks requires more time

   If the DB writes are slow, putting a queue in front of it won't make things faster. Jobs will still pile up in the queue and your next task will be figuring out why this happens. When dealing with complex ETL pipelines, improving performance becomes a quite tedious whack-a-mole operation where your bottlenecks just shift from system to system.
3. Cost per operation increases

   The more stages a job needs to traverse for its completion, the more time and money that job will require.

De-coupling components is usually seen as a silver bullet for dealing with performance issues. The correct separation of concerns and responsibilities is a very beneficial practice but requires a lot of experience and care. Nowadays monolithic services are seeing as the root of all evils. Personally I prefer to deal with a monolithic bunch of spaghetti rather than a distributed one.

Comment: If I use some very specific examples, to build on the question, how is performance affected? So, let the queue be AWS-SQS, and let the dB write be on MySQL. Does it still make sense to write to the queue and separately have another process writing from queue to dB? Is this faster, that writing to the dB directly and returning the response back to front end? (hoping, my question made sense)