# Is a decoupled middleware like RabbitMQ needed for read & write API calls to a cloud storage like Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, rabbitmq, middleware

Is it required to use a decoupled middleware (like RabbitMQ) to make API calls to a cloud storage (like Firebase or DO Spaces) database for reads and writes?

I know that RabbitMQ is a messaging service that will execute tasks, like writing to a database or calculating an algorithm, when the message is passed to a function that gets the consumer message, so wouldn't it be redundant to use it to for uploading data (even large files) to, or reading data from, a managed cloud-based database?

This is assuming that I will not be using any managed, pay-to-use cloud services like Firebase Cloud Messaging or CloudAMQP. The app in question will be a React Native app that will upload large files to DO Spaces, and store small bits of data, like user data, in a Firebase collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ is a message broker, it won't execute tasks but just deliver messages according to your routing topology. You will still need to implement both the producer which handles the communication with the client and the consumer which actually publishes the data into your cloud storage.

Moreover, it is [recommended against](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2017-12-29-part1-rabbitmq-best-practice.html#payload--rabbitmq-message-size-and-types) using RMQ for moving large binary data such as files.

I guess on a more general line, your question is whether it makes sense to have a queue between a frontend application and a storage backend. In this matter, you can read an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900035/is-it-valid-to-use-aws-sqs-as-a-write-queue-to-aurora-database-to-increase-syste) I already gave in the past.

Comment: I meant to say in a function that gets the consumer message. I'll edit the question.